# Kendo dropdownlist doesn't update when I change bound angular model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, kendo-ui

Below I have 2 dropdown lists, both bound to an Angular model. The first is a Kendo dropdown, the second is just a standard MVC dropdown. They both correctly display their initial selections. The second one correctly updates its selected item when I make a change to the underlying Angular model. Why doesn't the first one do the same?

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.HomeProvince)
                      .DataTextField("Text")
                      .DataValueField("Value")
                      .BindTo(Model.ProvinceList)
                      .OptionLabel("Select")
                      .HtmlAttributes(new { required = "required", ng_model = "model.HomeProvince", ng_pattern = "/^[1-9][0-9]{0,1}$/" })
                      )

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.HomeProvince, Model.ProvinceList, new { ng_model = "model.HomeProvince" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not know Kendo, but I do know that if you are working with 3rd party libraries updating data bound to angularjs models. You need to use `$scope.$apply`. This will force the digest cycle and angular will take care of the binding.